Summation of log time complexities
What is O(logn) + O(2log(n/2)) + O(4log(n/4)) ... + O(nlog1) ?
I think it is O(nlogn) . Please clarify if I am correct or not.
The recurrence relation I am trying to solve here is T(n)=2T(n/2)+ log(n), T(1)=1. Please help me with this.

In the recurrence relation, I will assume  log is log2.
We can prove that () is O() as follows:
First, we can see that () is increasing for increasing , so for asymptotic analysis we can just look at those  that are a power of 2, i.e. we can substitute  = 2.
Then:
      (2) = 20log(2) + 21log(2−1) + 22log(2−2) + ... + 2−1log(21) + 2log(20)
As log2(2) =  for non-negative integers , we can simplify:
      (2) = 20 + (−1)21 + (−2)22 + ... + 1⋅2−1 + 0
Grouping the positives together and the negatives together:
      (2) = (20 + 21 + 22 + 23 + ... + 2−1) −
[1⋅21 + 2⋅22 + 3⋅23 + ... + (−1)2−1]
The first parentheses wrap a partial sum of a geometric series, and thus equals 2−1:
      (2) = (2−1) − [1⋅21 + 2⋅22 + 3⋅23 + ... + (−1)2−1]
The square bracketed part can be split up in separate sums, again using the geometric sequence property:



[1⋅21 + 2⋅22 + 3⋅23 + ... + (−1)2−1] is sum of:




21 + 22 + 23 + ... + 2−2 + 2−1 = 2 − 21


22 + 23 + ... + 2−2 + 2−1 = 2 − 22


23 + ... + 2−2 + 2−1 = 2 − 23


...


2−2 + 2−1 = 2 − 2−2


2−1 = 2 − 2−1



The sum of the right-hand side expressions is:
      (−1)2 − (21 + 22 + ... + 2−1)
Again we have in parentheses a partial sum of a geometric sequence:
      (−1)2 − (2 − 2) = (−2)2 + 2
Injecting that back for the square-bracketed expression in (2):
      (2) = (2−1) − (−2)2 − 2
      (2) = 2 −  − 2 + 2+1 − 2
      (2) = 2+1 −  − 2, which is O(2), which is O().

Can be done much much easier. Look at this as a function of a real variable and take a derivative. It's a constant.

@n.m.couldbeanAI, cool, post it as an answer?

Lets look at them as functions of a real variable, call it x. What's the derivative?
Since (k log(x/k))' = k/x, the derivative of the whole sum is
1/x + 2/x + 4/x + 8/x + ... + x/x

which is kess than 2 by the sum of the geometric series. Thus the function itself is O(x).
In order to make this rigorous, we can continue the series from the left to infinity, so that its length is independent of x and taking the derivative us well-defined at all points (this only makes it larger by 1/x). I also ignore constant factors which arise from log bases ≠ e.

Obtaining Empirically Verified Solutions by Tree Method and Backwards Substitution
For this problem, we let  be a recurrence relation in the form:
[1]: 

Our actual recurrence is given as:
[2]: 


Note that  is not a constant as it depends on , so we cannot condense it into a negligible  component of our recurrence (more on this later). This takes us to our first solution combining the tree method with the concepts of empirical analysis to derive an asymptotic bound.
Tree Method + Empirical Verification
Let the following represent the recursive tree for  from [2]:
Fig.1: 

We can determine the bounds by adding up costs of the base cases which is simply equivalent to the number of leaves[1], i.e. branching factor to the power of the tree height () constant time calls, thus  or simply  . We then add this to the summation of all (significant) costs per level, giving us:
[3]: 

For simplicity, we refer to the summation component as  (you'll see why that notation is used).
[4]: 

The evaluation/expansion of this summation is quite tricky but other answers have provided that. However, a simpler approach is to empirically verify the relationship between  and ; i.e. the input size and growth of the summation. The following is a graph for the results of 1 million n-values/data points at intervals of 1000 (with each iteration being the square of itself), in the range of 1*103 to 1*109, meaning that the first and last n-values are (1*103)2 and (1*109)2 respectively.
Fig.2:

We can see line  assume a consistently inconsistent oscillating shape, as it zig-zags above and beneath , thus cementing its status as an oscillation function[2], hence, the notation[3].
Due to the oscillating nature, the peaks in  which periodically overtake  means we can't simply say  is  as it's not always true as we've seen above. Notwithstanding, the absolute difference (represented by the orange line), which we will denote as , between  and  is relatively negligible as a consequence of never exceeding  asymptotically; this allows us to take  as a consistent bound on the performance of the recurrence, therefore:
[5]:    
Stronger Argument:
From Fig.2, the fact that the peaks of  periodically reaches  but never crossing it implies that the highest possible value (or peak) of  is about twice the value of  as seen in Fig.3 below.
Fig.3:

It is now trivial that at the worst case possible:
[6]:    
Q.E.D.
Backwards Substitution Method
This is quite straightforward, we simply expand by recursively substituting a portion of the recurrence into itself until we have malleable generalized terms and then obtain the bounds from the kth term[4][5].


Since the remainder of  is equivalent to , this means  is simply equal to  +  (as we deduced in [3], and empirically verified in Fig.2). Hence, bringing us to the same conclusion as in [5]:

Q.E.D.
Further Reading & Notes

Goodrich and Tamassia presented sophisticated techniques for solving recurrences in Chapter 11 of 'Algorithm Design and Applications'.

Guzman & Limoanco conducted experiments on approximating asymptotic tight bounds via empirical analysis.

Educator/YouTuber Abdul Bari has a playlist on a wide range of recurrence relation problems and solutions where he explains each succinctly.

Source code for the visualization experiment can be found in this GitHub repo.


